# URL Link Files do not copy to external storage

Tags: https, url, copy-and-paste

I have saved URL links outside my FireFox browser inside a folder named "Research Website Links". I am not saving the URL links inside the FireFox Bookmark Manager because I need my URL links to be organized in folders containing PDF files, and Photos. I created these URL links by selecting them in the FireFox Address Bar and then just dragging them to my custom folder.

Here is the problem.  When I try to copy the folder to a USB stick or an external Hard Drive I get an error message that reads "Error While Copying..." When I expand "Show me details" it reads, "Error opening file and No such file or directory."  However, when I drag the URL link file to another folder located in the same hard drive the URL link file moves without a problem.   It is only when I try to move it to an external drive is when I get this error.

In short, why is Linux handling URL link files in such a way?

Is it because of a security reason?  If yes, can I change this security setting?

Is it an account permission issue that blocks the URL link file from being copied to an external hard drive?

Will changing my file manager from NEMO to Nautilus, Thunar, Dolphin, etc. fix this URL file copying problem?

In the Windows10 world URL links can be freely moved around all over the place without any copy errors. Additionally, when you perform a PROPERTIES check on a Windows10 Link file you see the actual HTTP address in the LOCATION field.  In contrast, performing the same PROPERTIES check on a Linux generated URL link file the LOCATION field shows a folder path.  Why does the LINUX URL file use a folder path and hide the HTTP address?  In short, how can I make my Linux OS handle URL link files in the same way they are handled in Windows10?  Any advice welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: have you tried compressing the directory and copying the compressed archive to the HDD? if the problem is indeed with the files being a URL links, archiving them might help to circumvent the problem.

Comment: Endrias, I tried that already. If I ZIP the folders I am able to move the URL links to an external storage device without any copy errors. But that does not solve the problem. The Linux URL links are useless in a Windows10 environment. They do not automatically open the website by double clicking the URL link file.  Is there any Linux app that will convert these Linux URL link files to usable HTTP links no matter what ever PC I move them to?  Can anybody out there please test this out and share if the same issue exists? This will tell me Linux does this to URL link files by design.